# Regarding xarray apply_ufunc

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I am trying to calculate daily Tmax from a 3 hourly global dataset. I can do it using groupby but I would like to figure out how I can reduce the computational time by using dask parallel operations (e.g. using apply_ufunc). If there is a good documentation on ufunc please let me know (the documentation on xarray wasn't detailed enough for me, left me a little confused, as I don't have any prior experience with dask). Thanks!!

Here is what my code looks like:

```
    TAS = xr.open_dataset(INFILE_template.format(YR, YR), chunks={'time':8})
    DAYMAX  = TAS.groupby('time.dayofyear').max(dim='time')
    DAYMAX.to_netcdf(OUTFILE_template.format(YR, YR))
```

Dimension of TAS are as below:

```
    <xarray.Dataset>
    Dimensions:  (lat: 720, lon: 1440, time: 2928)
    Coordinates:
    * lon      (lon) float64 0.125 0.375 0.625 0.875 1.125 1.375 1.625 1.875 ...
    * lat      (lat) float64 -89.88 -89.62 -89.38 -89.12 -88.88 -88.62 -88.38 ...
    * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2008-01-01 2008-01-01T03:00:00 ...
    Data variables:
    tas      (time, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<shape=(2928, 720, 1440),
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can already write your analysis with `groupby()` and other xarray methods, all of these are already parallelized with dask. `apply_ufunc` makes it easier to wrap *new* functionality to support xarray and dask, but all the built-in routines in xarray already uses `apply_ufunc` or something similar internally to support dask.

As a side note: if you could kindly elaborate on what you found confusing or missing from the xarray docs, we are always looking to improve them!

Comment: Sorry about a slow response. My main confusion has to do with the (i) 'input_core_dims', Is it always the dimension along which the calculation happens (ii) Does the input xr.Dataset has to be two dimensional for this to work (as in http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html example?) I suppose if that's the case then one stack and unstack lat and lon to one dimension before applying ufunc. (iii) Would this allow using inbuilt scipy functions (e.g. could one use scipy spearman function to apply ufunc). I suppose 1-2 more examples on that page could very helpful.

Comment: Btw thank you guys for all the documentation that already exists. It's super helpful. The above mention confusion could be just because I haven't been using xarray (and similar pkgs) for much long. Thank you again!

Comment: @Shrad I have similar questions in this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/xarray/z8ue0G-BLc8